# Jquery - Existe uma maneira de conectar botões?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html5

Sou iniciante em programação estou trabalhando com wordpress. No site em que estou ajudando eu tenho um Slider Revolution com 4 balões que servirão como botões. E no corpo do site eu tenho um plugin de Portfólio com filtros.

Eu gostaria de saber se tem um método para que:

- Eu consiga fazer com que quando alguém clicar em um dos balões ative o "botão" do filtro. (Não sei a classe que ativa a função).

  - Um método para achar a função caso o primeiro item não seja atendido.

Exemplo do caso:

```
<div id="1">
<a id="btn1" href="#">Primeiro "botão" sem Função<a>
</div>

<div id="2">
<a id="btn2" href="#">segundo "botão" com Função<a>
</div>
```

Eu gostaria que quando eu clicasse no btn1 ativasse o btn2.

Filtro - http://www.mperrenoud.com.br/home-4
Silde -  http://www.mperrenoud.com.br/

Os 2 irão na mesma pagina.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Veja se isso te ajuda:

HTML:

```
  <button class="btn btn-primary" id="first">1</button>
  <button class="btn btn-primary" id="second">2</button>
```

JS:

```
$('#first').click(function (e){
  e.preventDefault();
  $('#second').click(); 
});

$('#second').click(function (e){
  e.preventDefault();
  console.log('Teste')
});
```

http://jsbin.com/yebirozuxe/2/edit?html,js,console,output

Comment: Você é genial exatamente isso.

Answer (score 1):

Não sei se entendi direito sua pergunta, mas pelo que vi você quer disparar uma função de um botão quando clicado em outro, correto?

Eu usaria o jQuery Trigger - http://api.jquery.com/trigger/

```
// quando clica no btn 1
$("#btn1").on("click", function(){
  // Dispara btn2
  $("#btn2").trigger("click");
});

Quando clica em btn 2
$("#btn2").on("click", function(){
  // Faz algo
});
```

Comment: Muito obrigado !! ajudou muito.